# Case Sensitive Partition Column in hive

Tags: hive

I need to create partition on a column with an UPPERCASE Column Name. However, Hive converts all the column Names to lowercase implicitly. I am not able to get data in my `select *` query. I cannot change the Folder name to lowercase. Below is the `Create` query I am using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db.ALERT_DS_Hive_Test
PARTITIONED BY (PROC_ID String) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('casesensitive'='PROC_ID')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/sam/hive-test/ALERT_DS.avro/' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/user/sam/hive-test/ALERT_DS.avsc');
```

Comment: Why does the column name need to be uppercase?

Comment: What is the error in `select * ...` query?

Comment: The partitioning column is **not** part of your AVRO schema, by definition. Therefore your `CREATE TABLE` makes no sense -- Hive does not really care about about the location of the base table (which contains no data); it cares about the list of partitions, that you will declare with `ALTER TABLE` commands, each with a different LOCATION.

Comment: And if you really want to make your partitioning column case-sensitive, just use the regular syntax i.e. enclose it with back-quotes -- `partitioned by (\`WTF\` String)`

Comment: I have tried the back-quote option but still the partition column becomes lower case when i run describe formatted query on it.

Comment: And this partition column is not a part of avro schema

Comment: Hi @DivyanandSharma, did you find a solution to this?